# jenssegers/laravel-mongodb's where() and raw() produces different result for same query

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I am using `jessengers/laravel-mongodb` in one of my project. I would like to use raw `mongodb` query rather than the other functions in jessengers library. when i write a simple query using `raw()` to get two field values from database, it returns the complete document. So i tried with `where()` function, the cursor shows the requested fields only.

I am afraid why the same query shows two different results...

Here is the query with `where()` function:

```
$articleDataArray = Article::where('art_xml_data.article.article_id', '=', $articleId)
  ->get(['art_status', 'art_file_path']);
```

This query returns a cursor having art_status and art_file_path values only. (As per Neil Lunn's advice I have edited the question to include the result here.)
Result:
[image]
But the below query when written in `raw()` returns the complete fields in the matched document.

```
$articleDataArray = Article::raw()->find(
  array ('art_xml_data.article.article_id' => $articleId), 
  array ('art_status' => 1, 'art_file_path' => 1)
  )->toArray();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: You need to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Saying something **does not work** without providing a verifiable sample that others can reproduce the same result from is neither informative as a question nor likely to get you an accurate answer. Give us all the (minimal and necessary) code and **"small"** sample of data necessary to prove and reproduce your case and I'm sure someone will look into it.

Comment: @NeilLunn I have edited my question to include the result of each queries.. Thanks for the information..

Comment: The first notable thing is that `art_xml_data` appears to be completely missing from your initial result using `where()`. The most logical reason for this is that your class definition most likely does not include this property OR the definition is incorrect. Given the often "flexible" nature of XML ( albeit parsed into a BSON Document form and stored in MongoDB ), it seems very likely that your "class schema" does not define this field. Seems larvel is happy to "pass through" queries on attributes it does not know about, but it's not going to display them.

Comment: Also, FYI. Please **don't post screenshots**. Below 10 reputation you should be outright blocked from any attempt to do so. Up to 50 rep ( I think, could be higher or lower ) you should be *"warned"* at the very least. That "stuff" on your screen is "text". Just like everything else (including the code blocks) typed into the question. Please use **"text"** in future posts. Takes less keystrokes than screenshot to image conversion as well.

Comment: In the event you are actually only expecting the selected fields, that's actually `array( projection => array ('art_status' => 1, 'art_file_path' => 1))` or just `[ projection => [ 'art_status' => 1, 'art_file_path' => 1 ] ]` with modern PHP driver releases as opposed to *"old"* syntax for *projection* that you may have read elsewhere. See [Examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBCollection-find/#examples) in the PHP Driver documentation for `find()`.